# Android - buffer and selectively save 30s of video

Tags: android, video, encoding, camera, buffer

I want an app that'll take 30s of buffered video, but only save the buffer to a file when I press the shutter button. The application is for me to use it when I'm playing volleyball; when I make a big play I want to click one of those bluetooth shutter remotes and have a video I can look at later.

The most obvious solution I can think of is to have a ring buffer containing frames of the video and an audio ring buffer. But I've not written an Android app before and I don't want to bite off more than I can chew. Ideally I'd like to have source code for a similar app I can follow, and I haven't found any apps that use video ring buffers. Plus, synchronizing the audio seems like it might be tricky. And keeping 30s*60fps=1800 4K bitmaps in memory takes up a lot of RAM, and I can imagine that there's some solution that uses video encoding to save RAM.

So I'm thinking about just having two 30s video files that I alternate overwriting using the AOSP camera tutorial code. That is

- start up the app
- file 1 starts being written
- after 30 seconds, stop and start writing file 2
- after 30 seconds, stop and overwrite file 1
- button is pressed 15 seconds later: take the 15 seconds of file 1 and the last 15 of file 2 and stitch them together

But my concern there is that there may be some noticeable discontinuity at the stitching point, caused by the app not finishing writing file 2 and starting file 1 in less than one frame. Anyone have any thoughts on this?

A similar problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541542/how-can-i-save-video-frames-into-a-buffer), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277255/android-record-video-into-a-circular-buffer-and-storing-it-in-ram), [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426144/is-it-possible-to-record-video-from-the-camera-through-a-buffer-into-a-file), but the solutions are fairly old, predating the move to Kotlin. So I'm asking because there may be a more modern solution.